# Proof that the cardinality of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

Proof that the cardinality of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

I think is should be proved with the help of Cantor-Bernstein theorem.
It is easy to show that cardinality of of functions continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ is at least continuum - this set contains constant functions and there is natural bijection between them and $\mathbb{R}$. So we have one injection for the Cantor-Bernstein theorem. Can you please help with another? Or maybe there is another way, without Cantor-Bernstein theorem?

Comment: A continuous function is determined by its values on the rationals.

Comment: So more precisley the quation is to prove that the cardinality of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ is *equal* to the cardinality of $\mathbb R$. (The title is not completely clear about that)

Comment: @David Mitra, thanks, I see how to apply this argument to get second injection, but I have now idea on how to prove it :( Can you please suggest anything like references, keywords or maybe sketch of the proof?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen yes, your are right, I will edit it now.

Comment: @Hedgehog How many functions from the reals to the rationals?

Comment: "it"? The fact I gave above? If $f$ and $g$ are continuous with $f(a)\ne g(a)$, then $f(x)\ne g(x)$ for all $x$ in some open interval containing $a$; then $f$ and $g$ differ at a rational value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As David Mitra said, a continuous function is completely determined by its restriction to $\Bbb{Q}$. Hence, the following map is injective

$$
\Gamma : C(\Bbb{R}) \to \Bbb{R}^\Bbb{Q}, f \mapsto f|_\Bbb{Q}. 
$$

This implies

$$
|C(\Bbb{R})|\leq |\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{Q}|. 
$$

I will let you take it from here.

Hint:

> $|\Bbb{R}|=2^{|\Bbb{N}|}$

Comment: That is a nice hint.